# configure Ejabberd and Psi at localhost

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, psi, ejabberd-server

I have installed Ejabberd (ejabberd-18.09-windows) on win10 and I have set an admin (omar), I started It, and got this: [image]

Now I want to test it with some XMPP client, so I installed Psi, when I want to register an account, I got this :

[image]

Am 'I messing something? I didn't find any step-by-step ressource to do this (or I didn't get it).

**NB**: I run Ejabberd/XMPP server and client on the same machine, (how can I do it on separate machines?)

When I set Host/port manualy,  the resulte is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is listening for connections to "omar.org". But does your client know that "omar.org" can be found in the IP address "127.0.0.1"? Apparently it doesn't know.

You can setup DNS to direct omar.org to your machine.

Or you can tell Psi where that server is: in Psi -> Account Properties -> Connection -> Manually specify host/port -> Host: 127.0.0.1, Port: 5222

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I didn't add the SRV certificate, Now It works(manually as [badlop](/questions/tagged/badlop) suggested)